# angular - How to get a reference to each element generated by ngFor when it's created

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor

I'm trying to bind jQuery UI functionality on my elements after the are generated by ngFor. Therefore what I'm looking for is an event or something that I can use in my component, which provides a reference to the new element that's created.
Something like that:

sample.component.html

```
<!-- Parent div is the element I want a reference to each time it's created
     so I can automatically bind the functionality -->

<div *ngFor="let item of items"> 
    <img src="whatever.jpg">
    <p> some other stuff here </p>
<div>
```

sample.component.ts

```
/* Something like Angular lifecycle hooks */

onNewElement(el) {
   $(el).draggable();
}
```

Is there some kind of callback I can use or an angular method triggered after each element is generated? Any chance you can provide a sample?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use JQuery with Angular. You should not touche the DOM by yourself, you should let Angular do it.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" #elements> 
    <img src="whatever.jpg">
    <p> some other stuff here </p>
<div>
```

In your TS :

```
@ViewChildren('elements') els: QueryList<any>;
```

With this list of elements, you can get the reference of any element.

For instance, to get the first :

```
const first = this.els.first;
```

This will give you the element that you will be avle to manipulate with the renderer :

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

(Be advised that you need your view to be loaded in order to access the view children, this means that the last usable hook is `AfterViewInit`)

Comment: Thank you very much!
By the way I've already seen that many people discourage using jQuery, but it's functionality is vital in my project at this point.
Are you aware of some other module, angular native or not, that can provide that kind of functionality?

Comment: If you refer to the draggability of an element, know that **[this is native to HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)**, so you really don't need JQuery !

Answer (score 0):

Try this ? span is not going to create any css problems.

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of items"> 
      <span class="draggable">
        <img src="whatever.jpg">
        <p> some other stuff here </p>
      </span>
    <div>
```

Comment: Not only this doesn't answer the question, but why not simply put the class on the div ?

Comment: That way you can't provide some properties and values that need to be dynamically calculated and passed on initialization. Also i need to dynamically bind more functionalities besides jQuery methods. Therefore i need to know the right way like @trichetriche mentioned